# Print traceback from Pydantic to traceback without handling exceptions

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

## I want to get Pydantic error in traceback like in Pydantic v1 with detailed info without handling exceptions

### Error what I want to have:

```
File "/Users/kmsb/PycharmProjects/apiv1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
        response = await func(request)
    File "/Users/kmsb/PycharmProjects/apiv1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 291, in app
        content = await serialize_response(
    File "/Users/kmsb/PycharmProjects/apiv1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 154, in serialize_response
        raise ResponseValidationError(
    fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError(
    pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for PostOut
    response → votes
    field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

### But Im getting FASTAPI error in traceback and can't troubleshoot code without pydantic error data:

```
File "/Users/kmsb/PycharmProjects/apiv1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
response = await func(request)
File "/Users/kmsb/PycharmProjects/apiv1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 291, in app
    content = await serialize_response(
  File "/Users/kmsb/PycharmProjects/apiv1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 154, in serialize_response
    raise ResponseValidationError(
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError
```

## MY CODE

### Version

fastapi: 100+,
pydantic: 2+

### I have response model in my endpoint from Fastapi app which trigger that exception:

```
@router.post("", response_model=PostOut, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

### Pydantic model:

```
class PostOut(BaseModel):
    Post: PostBase
    votes: int
```

### If I write this block I can handle and read error:

```
@app.exception_handler(ResponseValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: ResponseValidationError):

    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": exc.errors(), "body": exc.body}),
    )
```

So how can this be done without handling function?